# What is the coproduct in the category of commutative rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, category-theory

My question: What is the coproduct in the category of commutative rings?

Comment: With or without unity?

Answer (score 7):

I will assume that you require your rings to be unital. Then the coproduct will just be the tensor product over $\mathbb{Z}$, i.e. the tensor product as $\mathbb{Z}$-modules (or equivalently abelian groups) with the induced ring structure.

Comment: Why does it needs to be over $\mathbb{Z}$ and not over an arbitrary ring $R$. I know that $\mathbb{Z}$ is initial object, but I can't see why

Comment: The category of rings is equivalent to the category of $\mathbb{Z}$-algebras. That is where that "choice" comes from. If you were to consider $R$-algebras instead, you would get the tensor product over $R$. To verify these claims, one just checks the universal property.